# Single function for saving into localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How can we save and retain localStorage objects rather than creating multiple functions ? The first localStorage object get replaced with the new save.  So to avoid that I have created a new function called `saveLocalStorageDataTwo` which is working. But how can we avoid creating multiple functions for saving data into the localStorage ? Is there any way ? Could some please advise ?

/* localStorage.js  */

```
let localStorageData = {};
let localStorageDataTwo = {};

function saveLocalStorageData ({autoId, quoteId, taskId }) {
    localStorageData = {
        autoId: autoId,
        quoteId: quoteId,
        taskId: taskId,
    }
    return localStorageData
}

function saveLocalStorageDataTwo ({data}){
    localStorageDataTwo = {
        data : data,
    }
    return localStorageDataTwo
}

export { saveLocalStorageData, saveLocalStorageDataTwo };
```

// Saving to localStorage:

```
let localData = require("../../support/localStorage");

const data = "Some Data 260-255"
const localStorageData = localData.saveLocalStorageData({ autoId });
window.localStorage.setItem('localStorageData ', JSON.stringify(localStorageData ));
```

[image]

Comment: your functions are not storing anything in local storage

Comment: Yes it is storing , in first scenario I am calling ` const localStorageData = localData.saveLocalStorageData({ autoId });` to save the data.. This is saving succesfuly. But in third scenario I have to do another save  for some other data ```const localStorageData = localData.saveLocalStorageData({ taskId }) ``` ..this overwrites/ replace my first save ...as the first data is required to search something in second scenario

Comment: @soccerway It's obvious it's being overridden. But it depends on **what do you exactly want?** Update an Object and add just a property? An Array and add a new entry? Different localStorage properties?

Comment: unclear why you need to destructure params, simply add another function param which can be used as the object key, then make `localStorageData`, `data` (it doesn't need to be explanatory) and then make the simple object, i.e `data[key] = values`, ideally localData should have `.set(key, value)`, `.get(key, default)`, `.isset(key)`, `.remove([ key])`, `.clear()` else really there is no point in abstracting it

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  I will explain again, 
1. In Scenario 1, I have saved my first data  ``const localStorageData = localData.saveLocalStorageData({ autoId });``  and this is available. 
2. In Scenario 2, I have used localStorage getItem to get the above first data to perform some operation.
3. In Scenario 3, I have saved another data  ``const localStorageData = localData.saveLocalStorageData({ taskId });`` this replace my first data with second save. So how can we avoid this by using the same function ?

Comment: @soccerway let me repeat. What is the expected localStorage state after you save your other data? Update/merge with the first one? Create a new entry in localstorage? Add it to an Array? Insert it into an Object as a new Proeprty?

Comment: If I could update with the first one and appears like this 
localStorageData  [ {"autoId": 300} , {"taskId": 100} ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You simply don't use any strict params like `{autoId, quoteId, taskId}` just pass any arbitrary `data`.
- Don't call something `saveLocalStorageData` if that's actually ***not*** what that function does.

Instead:

```js
const LS = {
  set(key, data) { localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(data); },
  get(key) { return JSON.parse(localStorage[key]); },
};
// export { LS };
```

```js
// import { LS } from "./localstorage.js"

// Example saving multiple data in different LS keys
LS.set("one", {autoId: 1, quoteId: 2, taskId: 3});
LS.set("two", {autoId: 7});


// Example saving Object, and later update one property value
const data = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
LS.set("single", data); // Save
LS.set("single", {...LS.get("single"), c: 99999}); // Update
console.log(LS.get("single")); // {a:1, b:2, c:99999}


// Example saving multiple data into a single Array:
LS.set("arr", []); // Save wrapper Array
LS.set("arr", LS.get("arr").concat({a: 1, b: 2}));
LS.set("arr", LS.get("arr").concat({e: 7, f: 9}));
console.log(LS.get("arr")); // [{"a":1,"b":2}, {"e":7,"f":9}]
```

*[jsFiddle playground](https://jsfiddle.net/sx0w2fuk/)*

or in the last example instead of an Array you could have used an Object. It all depends on the needs.

Comment: Thank you mate ! Will try this approach.. I have added a screenshot into the question.  I will try to follow >> ```  just pass any arbitrary data.```

Comment: @soccerway explore slowly and with understanding all the three examples I provided. You're welcome.